# If a natural number $x$ is divisible by $3$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, divisibility

Is the sentence

> If a natural number $x$ is divisible by $3$ then, if it is not divisible by $3$ then it is divisible by $5$

true or false?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: it could be either

Comment: I know it's true, but how to prove it.

Comment: This is just one of those silly things where it is true vacuously.

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the statement "a natural number x is divisible by 3" as $p$ and "a natural number x is divisible by 5" as $q$.

Then the given statement can be represented in propositional logic notations as,

$p \Rightarrow (\neg p \Rightarrow q) \\or,p\Rightarrow (\neg(\neg p) \lor q)\\or,p \Rightarrow (p \lor q)\\or, \neg p \lor p \lor q\\or, TRUE  $

Thus the statement is always true.

Answer (score 1):

A material conditional is false if and only if it has both a true antecedent and a false consequent. Suppose then that the statement “If a natural number x is divisible by 3 then, if it is not divisible by 3 then it is divisible by 5” is false. This is the case if and only if both "x is divisible by 3" is true and "if x is not divisible by 3 then it is divisible by 5" is false. But the conditional "if x is not divisible by 3 then it is divisible by 5" is false if and only if both "x is not divisible by 3" is true and "x is divisible by 5" is false. So both "x is divisible by 3" is true and "x is not divisible by 3" is true, a contradiction.